# Netsh Helper Dll On Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, netsh

I'm programming some stuff using .Net Framework on Windows 10.

Well I started a cmd.exe process, and I tried to use the command `netsh wlan` but it doesn't work and return something like `cannot find command wlan`.

I still can run `netsh wlan` command when I launch cmd.exe individually; just unable to run it when I start cmd.exe in my .Net app.
I also found the helper dll list (when I used `netsh show helper` command) aren't the same when I launch cmd.exe individually. I've tried to run `netsh add helper wlancfg.dll` but it doesn't work.

I used to do the same thing on Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1. All of it worked like a charm, however it doesn't work on Windows 10.

EDIT: I think the problem is not how my code is, but netsh doesn't load wlancfg.dll because when I use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe")` to start it and type `netsh`, it has the same problem.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I found the answer myself.
The problem is that my Windows 10 is 64bit. So there's is some WoW64 Filesystem Redirection.
Just using the API `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I using this command for interacting with cmd in my applications try this:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c netsh wlan ...")
    {
      WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    });
```

Comment: Which is the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: you can create this process as many as you want and you can use /k to doesn't close cmd for other commands you can see other arguments for more info [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Comment: it doesn't work because netsh.exe still doesn't load wlancfg.dll.